# Bounty hunters WANTED?

Tags: discussion

[image]

I here by call ALL - support our bounties.

We don't have many offered on the site, but when there is one - I think it's an effort to at least upvote it.

The ones we have have a very low votes for them.

I am not saying blindly upvote, but once a bounty is offered:

1. It's not a new user - most chances it's not a stupid question (??  ^^)
2. OP probably is urgently looking for an answer - high traffic on the question - upvotes - can also increase it's visibility on the site.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured

just my 2cents

Comment: Now uses can just *buy* a [guaranteed answer with 50 unicoins](http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/620/unicoins-love-it-use-it)

Comment: i'm not smart enough to answer hard questions :(